# jQuery change event handler stop working on mandatory SharePoint fields

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have created a jQuery change event handler which works ok on a normal drop down (choice) field, but as soon as I change that filed property to "Require that this column contains information" = Yes then the event handler will no longer trigger. Any idea how to overcome this?

This is the original code. Could you recommend how to fix it?

```
$("select[title='Unit']").change(function() { 
    var UnitField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Unit').GetValue();
    if ( ITCUnitField.indexOf("Unit 1") >= 0) 
    {
        alert("Are you sure you belong to Unit 1"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the original code. Could you recommend how to change it?

Comment: $("select[title='Unit']").change(function() {

 var UnitField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Unit').GetValue();

 if ( ITCUnitField.indexOf("Unit 1") >= 0)
 {
  alert("Are you sure you belong to Unit 1");
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

Conflicting events, and SharePoint's took priority. Easy workaround is to just bind to a different event like Click or MouseUp.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution!

if you add "Required Field" to the field name in the select statement then that will work as expected.

```
$("select[title='Unit Required Field']").change(function() {...
```